# Is Ki-Adi-Mundi married to multiple wives in Disney Canon?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

In Legends, Jedi Master Ki-Adi-Mundi was said to have several wives. While this was normally against the Jedi Order's rules regarding attachments, an exception was made for him because of the low population of his species. (I think this was a retcon to explain why the comics said that he was married, but then *Attack of the Clones* came out and established that Jedi couldn't have attachments).

Did any of this transfer to Disney Canon? Did he ever mention being married to multiple wives, perhaps in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV show?

Comment: An "exception", sure. Just another example of Jedi corruption.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No, he's not married

This idea has been completely discounted in canon; Pablo Hidalgo confirmed as much [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/SunBeneathSea1/status/788811263845564416) in October 2016:

[image]

> **@SunBeneathSea1** shouldn't the jedi council have seen how happy ki adi mundi was and realize the no attachment rule was stupid.
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Ki-Adi-Mundi does not have a bunch of wives. That was an unfortunate idea in the EU.
>
> **@SunBeneathSea1** does he at least have one wife or is it no longer canon he was allowed to have a family due to the low populace of his species
>
> **@pablohidalgo** He is not married at all. And he is a Jedi Master on the Council.

Comment: Also your instincts were correct: this is very much a retcon. And not the only one related to this character; it was also said at one point that he was a Jedi Knight while serving on the Council, which rather takes the wind out of Anakin's sails in *Revenge of the Sith* (this is what Hidalgo is referring to with his last sentence in that last tweet)